# Create typescript interface as union of other interfaces

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a list of interfaces that extends one basic interface.

I have also some functions that can accept any of these interfaces.

I would like to create a new interface that describe that kind of parameter.

So I have something like this:

```
interface BasicInterface {...};

interface A extends BasicInterface {...};
interface B extends BasicInterface {...};
```

and I would like something like

```
interface C = A | B;
```

I know in my functions I can do

```
function X(param1: A | B) {};
```

but since it is more than one function I would like to have just one interface for all of them.

Comment: does X need more than what's in BasicInterface?

Comment: @toskv yes, it does a check on a property of `BasicInterface` then uses specific properties of every interface

Comment: what is the problem? because you could easily define a param signature as you did (apart from the fact if that is realy such a good idea)

Comment: @robkuz I would like to have a type for `param1`, to have something like `function X(param1: C) {}`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So, after some digging in the Typescript documentation I've found what I was looking for: [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases).

I can declare a new type like `type C = A | B;`

Then in function I use type guards to access the right thing:

```
function isA(param: C): param is A {
    return param.type === A;
}

function X(param1: C) {
  if (isA(param1)) //things related to A
  else //things related to B
};
```

Comment: Where do you get the prop `type` from (`param.type === A`)?

Comment: @olefrank well, this is up to you. Take a look to the section `User-Defined Type Guards` here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: why is this giving me an intersection and not union?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly you cannot use an `interface` to define an union type directly.

It is possible to do it only indirectly using a type, for instace:

```
interface A {
    x: 'x';
}
interface B {
    y: 'y';
}

type C = A | B; // Union of interfaces using a type
```

More information and example on this page: [TypeScript Book](https://github.com/gibbok/typescript-book#differences-between-type-and-interface)