# Passing union typed props to react child component requiring one of the types in the union

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

In Typescript+React. I've got two components (modules) with specific types specified with an interface. In addition I've got one parent component which takes an array with a union specified as props.

The child components:

**Module One**

```
interface IModuleOneProps {
  moduleOneSpecificProp: string;
  module_type: sting;
  commonProp: string;
}

const ModuleOne: React.SFC<IModuleOneProps> = props => {
  return (
    <p>{moduleOneSpecificProp + " " + commonProp}</p>
  );
};

export default ModuleOne;
```

**Module Two**

```
interface IModuleTwoProps {
  moduleTwoSpecificProp: string;
  module_type: sting;
  commonProp: string;
}

const ModuleTwo: React.SFC<IModuleTwoProps> = props => {
  return (
    <p>{moduleTwoSpecificProp + " " + commonProp}</p>
  );
};

export default ModuleTwo;
```

The container component which contains an array of modules, which can be of both types:

```
interface IContainerModuleProps {
modules: Array<
    IModuleOneProps | IModuleTwoProps
  >;
}

class ContainerModule extends React.Component<IContainerModuleProps> {

  public render() {
    const module = this.props.modules[1];
    switch (module.module_type) {
      case 'module_one':
        return <ModuleOne {...module} />;
      case 'module_two':
        return <ModuelTwo {...module} />;
    }
  }
}
```

But TypeScript won't let me spread `module` when rendering the components. It complains about the types.

```
Type '{ commonProp: string; moduleOneSpecificProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IModuleOneProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{ commonProp: string; moduleTwoSpecificProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IModuleOneProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
    Property 'moduleOneSpecificProp' is missing in type '{ commonProp: string; moduleTwoSpecificProp: string; }'.
```

Is there a quick fix I'm not seeing here? Or do I have to rebuild the prop object (`module`) before passing it down to the child component?

Comment: How `module_type` property defined?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Sorry, just added it to the interfaces. That is being populated in an earlier function based on api call.

Comment: I just managed to solve the problem. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156270/create-typescript-interface-as-union-of-other-interfaces. I'll write up my solution shortly. Edit: Titian beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `module_type` property as a string literal type (a string type that an have only one value) if you do so, then the `switch` will type guard correctly:

```
interface IModuleOneProps {
    moduleOneSpecificProp: string;
    commonProp: string;
    module_type: "module_one"
}
interface IModuleTwoProps {
    moduleTwoSpecificProp: string;
    commonProp: string;
    module_type: "module_two"
}
interface IContainerModuleProps {
    modules: Array<
    IModuleOneProps | IModuleTwoProps
    >;
}

public render() {
    const module = this.props.modules[1];
    switch (module.module_type) {
        case 'module_one':
            return <ModuleOne {...module} />;
        case 'module_two':
            return <ModuleTwo {...module} />;
    }
}
```

It is also perfectly possible to use an enum for the string literals to avoid being dependent on magic strings:

```
enum MODULE_NAME {
  MODULE_ONE,
  MODULE_TWO
}
```

And then use `MODULE_NAME.MODULE_ONE` on both the interface and in the render method.

Comment: Thanks, just arrived at that solution. Which in practice was adding a new property (which I named `kind` according to http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) since the `module_type` property was being filled by API calls.

Comment: @PerEnström I just posted my answer when I saw your comment