# Is it possible to have a TypeScript interface that is made up of a second OR a third interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

Let’s say I have two interfaces:

```
export interface IStandardFilter {
    [key: string]: {
        include?: string[];
        exclude?: string[];
    };
}

export interface IArchivedFilter {
    archived: 'true' | 'false' | 'all';
}
```

and I would like to combine these two interfaces to make a third interface. How do I characterize this interface?

To give some context, right now I have this:

```
const defaultFilters: (IStandardFilter | IArchivedFilter)[] = [
    {
        'archived': 'false',
    },
    {
        'name': {
            include: [ 'bob' ];
            exclude: [ 'dobbs' ];
        }
    },
]
```

but on that first line I’d rather have something like

```
const defaultFilters: IComplexFilters[] = [...
```

So how do I define `IComplexFilters`? (edited)

Comment: You mean `type IComplexFilters = IStandardFilter | IArchivedFilter;` ?

Comment: Can you use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) like `type IComplexFilters = IStandardFilter | IArchivedFilter`?  It's not an interface, though.  If that doesn't work for you, can you show exactly where?  If it does work, let me know and I (or maybe someone else) will write up an answer (or close this as a duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create typescript interface as union of other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156270/create-typescript-interface-as-union-of-other-interfaces)