# how to conditionally add an object to an array of typed values

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to conditionally add object to and array of typed values but receive an error
tried with spread operator or to export to a function :(

Assuming

```
interface Foo {
   type:'foo';
   cool: string;
}
interface Bar {
   type: 'bar';
   lame: string;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar


const arr: FooBar[] = [
   {
      type: 'foo',
      cool: 'this works great!',
   },
   ...(true &&       //  <---- Will through error Types of property 'type' are incompatible 'string' is not assignable to '"bar" | "foo"' 
      [
       {
          type: 'bar',
          lame: 'WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE',
       }
   ]),
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a reason not to, TypeScript assumes string literals are of type `string`. In your question, the first object *isn't* treated that way because it's immediately being stored in an array where the string literal type `"foo"` is valid but `string` isn't.

So why isn't your second object given the same treatment? Because it isn't used immediately in a context where TypeScript can apply that. It's part of an expression (`true && {/*...*/}`), so the `type` property is just typed as `string`, and that isn't assignable to the literal types `"foo"` or `"bar"`.

You can fix it by adding `as const` to the array you're spreading, since that tells TypeScript the property won't be reassigned, so it can keep its narrowest type (`"bar"` in this example):

```
interface Foo {
   type:'foo',
   cool: string,
}
interface Bar {
   type: 'bar'
   lame: string,
}

type FooBar = | Foo | Bar

const arr: FooBar[] = [
   {
      type: 'foo',
      cool: 'this works great!',
   },
   ...(true && 
      [
       {
          type: 'bar',
          lame: 'WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE',
       }
      ] as const // <====
     ),
]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRYAngA4QBcA5DJtQDQFHIKYA2lyAzmFKAHMm+AL4FQkWIhQAhOFBzNi5KsmoAjedSXJ2cALare-EEIJj8BUhTSY5CgLzIAPrayv7BAmxC9k8qC4MdHsAbQBdZCdQnTxCFmUKLlp6YQSiNnRONTAAC2BuZAB3dCgAa0KBKAg4MABCRh0RNKIAOnaACj4AVxQAMj7kHRYY+PS49PTrVQ0tFsmiPUNkgHUACQBNZAAVNYBJAGVkAFEAJVOAeVPkC4A5HY2ABWPGsYSLSci4Qp8-AHo-sgADwOUEOYbIACUwnCQA)

(Note I've also had to fix a couple of syntax errors. You can't use `interface FooBar =`, so I've used `type` instead, and the closing quote on the `lame` property wasn't the same kind as its opening quote.)

Comment: Thanks so much you're a life saver (also sorry for the typo's I wrote it on the fly and didn't notice)

Answer (score 0):

Common error. The problem here is just what the compiler is saying:
*Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar"'*

You need a cast from string to string literal. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528)

What you can do:

- this: type "bar" as Bar
- or: type "foo" as Foo
- or better in your case: type "foo" as const

There are other errors in your code:

- change
  `interface FooBar = | Foo | Bar` for `type FooBar = Foo | Bar` . It's called [type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156270/create-typescript-interface-as-union-of-other-interfaces).
- change
  `lame: 'WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE"` for `lame: "WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE"`. You can't start a string with single quote and end with double quote.

The adjusted final code:

```js
interface Foo {
  type: "foo";
  cool: string;
}

interface Bar {
  type: "bar";
  lame: string;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

const arr: FooBar[] = [
  {
    type: "foo",
    cool: "this works great!",
  },
  ...(true && [{
    type: "bar" as const,
    lame: "WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE",
  }]),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're initializing an unknown array, and spreading it;
Let the array know that you're creating an array of `FooBar[]`;

```
...(true && [{
    type: 'bar',
    lame: 'WHY THIS ERROR ON TYPE',
}] as FooBar[])
```

Here is the [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkFgCeADhAFzIDkMmVANPgQpgDaUDOYUoA5owF9coSLEQoAQnCg4myYmUpUARtKpzWcALYVkXHiH64huBSgzopMgLxpMyAD7IrAbly4WILsmlRKFqwBtAF1kW0C5WQJo6LMlWnQGSJiWdHZqMAALYA5kAHd0KABrXN4oCDgwAEIkmIFGGIA6ZoAKbgBXFAAyLuRAvBiYuOpVKFrBgk0dJQB1AAkATWQAFTmASQBlZABRACVdgHld5AOAORWFgAVt8YIBULhcgOkQgEpcYNwgA)